# SQL command to skip header/title row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to know if there is a SQL command which can disable/hide headers (field names) from SELECT query. Right now each time I run my query and generate .csv it shows field names in the very first row. I am on a platform where I do no have direct access to database.

Comment: SELECT commands don't output a "header". That must be an artifact of whatever layer is between you and the database.

Comment: So you mean I can not directly disable field names being populated on the first row of the csv? Wondering if I can add a switch like skip-headers or something to my query just to avoid them or something tricky?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a SQL feature, but a feature of the environment where you run the SQL and then export it to CSV. Some environments offer this feature, some do not.

Comment: As you stated that you are using MS SQL Server in another comment, in SQL Server Management Studio, you can go to Tools/Options/Query Resuöts/SQL Server/Results to Text, and there is a checkbox `Include column headers in the result set`.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Actually I don't have access to DBMS. All I can run SELECT type queries, so your answer is quite helpful. I just thought there might be a command unknown to me. Thank you so much for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeeeep, mySQL has a skip-column-names option that can be applied when you invoke your MySQL connection.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html

Comment: How do you know OP was using mySQL?